# how to remove enclosed whitespaces in sublime text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I just installed sublime text 3; when I save the script and run it, whitespace and first line is enclosed with a rectangles.  How can I remove those?  I have attached the screen shot.[image]

I have Anaconda on my machine but I don't see it under Package Settings. [image]

Comment: I would check the settings for the Sublime Linter packgages; the rectangles are likely linter warnings (i.e. Sublime doesn't do that sort of thing by default). Probably the status bar also tells you what each box is warning you of if you place the text cursor inside them, for example.

Comment: @OdatNurd-Thanks! I removed the linter and it fixed the rectangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there was a conflict with other packages or there is a bug in pylint but after I removed sublimelinter.pylint, the rectangles were gone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Anaconda package? 
If yes, you need to set anaconda_linting to false in the settings.

To do this - 
Go to Preferences → Package Settings → Anaconda → Settings-User. 
Then paste the following code and save.

{
    "anaconda_linting": false,
}

Comment: @DavidBreen-I have Anaconda on my machine but it is not listed under package Settings. please see the screen shot in my post above

Comment: I have the following packages:
  "BracketHighlighter",
  "Dayle Rees Color Schemes",
  "Emmet",
  "Package Control",
  "SideBarEnhancements",
  "SublimeCodeIntel",
  "SublimeLinter",
  "SublimeLinter-pylint"